# How to filter tolist query results based on a foreign key in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, filter, model

I have two Classes Task & User.  I want to be able to filter the tasks based on the value of the User class attribute "Name".

```
public class Task
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

////UsersController

```
    public ActionResult UserTasks()
    {
        return View(db.Tasks.Where(Task => Task.User == User.Name).ToList());
    }
```

Also tried the UserTasks functions with == User.UserID, also didn't work.

Comment: this is a bit unclear.  Describe if you want a one to one, one to many or many to many relationship here... and/or post any code you've tried and any errors you receive.

Comment: user: task -> 1: many  The code under userscontroller is what I have tried -> error: 'IPrincipal' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no accessible extension method 'Name' etc...

Comment: It should be `db.Tasks.Where(task => task.User.Name == user.Name)` assuming you retrieved the User object already into a variable called user. My recommendation would be to get the user id with something like `db.Users.Where(x => x.Name == user.Name).FirstOrDefault().UserID` and then retrieve related tasks with `db.Tasks.Where(x => x.UserID == userId).ToList();`